# May I Invest as a non accredited investor?

Tags: stocks, investing, options

I want to join a website where they allow only accredited investors to participate in investments that they manage.

I am not an accredited investor. However, in the past, I worked for the company and acquired stock in the company itself. Does me holding stock in the company make me an accredited investor with this company in particular?

I'm guessing probably not, but its nice to ask and cover my bases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Does me holding stock in the company make me an accredited investor with this company in particular?" No.

But maybe the site will let you trade it your shares to another accredited investor. Just ask, if the site operators have a securities lawyer they should be able to accomodate

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you're saying. To liquidate the equity that I old? If i understood correctly. I'd like to participate in their managed investments in the role of an accredited investor - while not being one... this isn't possible. ok. 

Then are you saying I may contact an investor and 'piggy back' off of them?

Comment: @ZiggidyCreative you started asking about investing in a company, but then mentioned you have shares in "the company" already. You want to invest MORE? No you can't. You want to find an accredited investor to sell your shares to? Yes you can.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to invest any more in the company itself, I'd just like to participate in the investment opportunities that the company manages. But Yeah i guess this isn't possible unless im accredited. I heard it may be possible since I hold shares with them. Oh well. Thanks for the insight @cqm

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics it is hard to give you a specific answer, but most likely the answer is no. If they limit the participation in the site to accredited investors, this is probably not something they are doing willingly, but rather imposed by regulators. Acredited investors have access to instruments that don't have the same level of regulatory protection & scrutiny as those offered to the general public, and are defined under Regulation D. 
Examples of such securities are 144A Shares, or hedgefunds.